# Linking data leading to inaccurate estimates -- Stata

Tags: stata

I am linking seven datasets in stata using the following code:

```
clear all 

*Import RUCC
import delimited "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FDobkin/HPSA-paper/main/rucc.csv"

*Keep California
keep if state == "CA"

*Drop variables
drop county population state

*Rename FIPs
rename ïfips countyfips

*Save
tempfile rucc
save `rucc'

clear
*Upload CDC data (n=8005)
import delimited "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FDobkin/HPSA-paper/main/brffs.csv", stringcols(1)

*Merge
merge m:1 countyfips using `rucc'
drop _merge

*Save locally
tempfile disease
save `disease'

clear

*Upload demographic data
import delimited "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FDobkin/HPSA-paper/main/demographics.csv", stringcols(1)

*Rename census_id
rename ïcensus_id census_id

*Merge
merge 1:m census_id using `disease'
drop _merge

*Save locally
tempfile demographic
save `demographic'

clear all

*Upload HPSA
import delimited "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FDobkin/HPSA-paper/main/hpsa.csv", stringcols(1)

*Merge
merge m:1 census_id using `demographic'
drop _merge

*Save locally
tempfile acs
save `acs'

*Clear
clear all

*Upload ACS
import delimited "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FDobkin/HPSA-paper/main/acs.csv", stringcols(5)

*Merge with HPSA
merge 1:1 census_id using `acs'
drop _merge

*Generate HPSA status
gen hpsa = 0 if hpsa_score == .
replace hpsa = 1 if hpsa_score !=.

*Save locally
tempfile acs_hpsa
save `acs_hpsa'

*Clear
clear all

*Upload CES
import delimited "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FDobkin/HPSA-paper/main/ces.csv", stringcols(1)

*Merge
merge m:1 census_id using `acs_hpsa'

*Keep columns 
drop _merge hpsa_score 

*Encode numeric values 
foreach var in drink_water traffic med_popr med_pop_o65r lead lbw cardi_disease educ ling_isolation poverty unemployment housing_burden age_over64 perc_afam perc_hispanic perc_white perc_native_am perc_asian perc_other {
    encode `var', gen(`var'_)
    drop `var'
}

*Save
tempfile ca_file
save `ca_file'

clear 

*Import broadband
import delimited "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FDobkin/HPSA-paper/main/perc_broadband.csv", stringcols(1)

*Recode broadband 
encode perc_broadband, gen(broadband)
drop perc_broadband

*Merge
merge m:1 census_id using `ca_file'
keep if _merge == 3
drop _merge
```

When I upload the datasets individually, the summary statistics are accurate, however, when I link the datasets together, the summary statistics are substantially off e.g. the mean percentages of ethnicity exceed 300. It looks like the issue is taking place at the loop. Is there something wrong with the loop that throws off the values or is the issue somewhere else?

Comment: Goodness knows, except that the presence of `encode`  statements rings alarm bells of mammoth proportions. Why are those regarded as string any way? I guess wildly that the `encode` is a work-around for metadata that is present in the data and/or codes for missing values that aren't Stataish.

Comment: Before the first loop with `encode` statements, look at the data with `tab1 drink_water traffic med_popr med_pop_o65r lead lbw cardi_disease educ ling_isolation poverty unemployment housing_burden age_over64 perc_afam perc_hispanic perc_white perc_native_am perc_asian perc_other`

Comment: Thanks for the advise. It looks like the data was preserved up until that point. I ended up using gen var = real(var) instead which seemed to work.